# ASP.NET MVC 4 remove "WWW" from the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

What is the expression to remove the "WWW" and redirect permanently to the same url. Can you please help me with the HttpRedirect rule. (C#)

ex: www.domain.com -> domain.com
ex: www.domain.com/Home -> domain.com/Home

Comment: This is a feature of the web server. See [IIS Url Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module).

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with MVC, and as @Romoku said has more to do with the Web Server configuration.

Comment: I am not sure he understands MVC routing.   Explanation below.

Comment: Is there any way to remove the "WWW"?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is gain an understanding of MVC routing.   There is a good tutorial here

[ASP.NET MVC Routing Overview (C#)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs)

Take a look at the RouteConfig class in the App_Start folder.  You will note the following code snippet there

```
routes.MapRoute( 
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" } // Parameter defaults
);
```

what this code does is to redirect (choice of words?) any incoming request that does not match a specific custom route (see Custom Routes tutorial above) to the following default action method in the HomeController.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "You have found the Home page.";

    return View();
}
```

If you want to access the url you can do so through the Request property of HttpContext

```
var url = HttpContext.Request.Url;
```

There is also an MVC class called UrlHelper which can be useful for building urls within an MVC application

[UrlHelper Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

The following blog post demonstrates how to build an absolute action using UrlHelper

[How to Build Absolute Action URLs Using the UrlHelper Class](http://blog.mariusschulz.com/how-to-build-absolute-action-urls-using-the-urlhelper-class)

You may want to configure a virtual directory for your application

[Virtual Directory Setup Instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751432.aspx)

and you can configure redirect in IIS itself

[HTTP Redirects](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpredirect)

I hope this helps!